# How to map and store countries and currencies in JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, underscore.js

I have three different currencies and each currency is mapped to multiple countries. The third currency(EUR) is mapped to several countries. How can I structure my data in a javascript array to easily get the corresponding currency code by country. I have the following data, what is the best way to structure to easily access it with country code.

```
USD - en-US,es-MX
GBP - en-GB
EUR - de-AT,nl-BE,el-CY,et-EE,fi-FI,fr-FR,de-DE,el-GR,en-IE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Practically you can do a re-map operation like this;

```js
var data = { 
    USD : ["en-US","es-MX"],
    GBP : ["en-GB"],
    EUR : ["de-AT","nl-BE","el-CY","et-EE","fi-FI","fr-FR","de-DE","el-GR","en-IE"]
},
  curMap = {};
Object.keys(data).forEach(k => data[k].forEach(c => curMap[c] = k));
console.log(curMap);
```

Comment: I don't want to do foreach loop. If I pass any country code, I simply need to  get its currency code. The time may not be a problem. I hardly have 50 countries for EUR, the code anyway runs on the client machine.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an object, its constant time lookup, as opposed to an array that you would have to loop over:

```
var currencies = {
  'de-AT': 'EUR',
  'nl-BE': 'EUR'
  ...
}
```

If you use an array:

```
var currencies = {
 'USD': ['en-US', 'es-MX']
 ...
}
```

While it might look cleaner, and easier to make, it will be slower, as you would have to loop through each array to check if the item is there

Comment: In the first approach, I need to add 50 entries for EUR code. In the second approach, how can I simply get the currency code based on country? Is there any better alternative using JQuery, UnderscoreJS, backboneJS...etc?